How to inverse a dictionary where one of the values has multiple values/items in it?
I am currently trying to figure out how to inverse a dictionary, but for some reason the inversed dictionary is cutting out the last key:value pair. The value has 2 items in it instead of one, which is the only difference between the other key:value pairs. With my current code, it inverses the first 3 names and numbers, but the last one doesn't even show up in the inverse. How would I inverse all four values in the dictionary?
contacts = {
    "John A": "858 900 1001", 
    "Jillian": "858 900 1002", 
    "Ron": "858 900 1003", 
    "Miranda": { "mobile": "858 900 1004", "home": "555 1284" }
}
sorted(contacts.keys())
for key in contacts:
    value = contacts[key]
    if key == "Miranda" and 'mobile' in value:
        print(f"contact: {key}, mobile number: {value['mobile']}")
    else:
        print(f"contact: {key}, mobile number: {value}")
contacts_inv = {value: key for key, value in contacts.items() if isinstance(value, str)}
print(contacts_inv)

I tried using the standard inverse {v: k for k, v in contacts.items() if isinstance(value, str)} method but that didn't inverse all the values, only the first 3.

Well you explicitly tell it to only include the string values, not the nested dictionaries. It would probably a better design decision overall to make all values the same type

Either flatten your dictionary where standard inverse for one-to-one lookup may apply, or format your internal data to contain common inner keys where you will be able to follow the guide in this thread.

Is there a way to do it without importing defaultdict from collections?

What do you expect the key to be when you invert the last entry?

You have to adjust your inversion logic to deal with nested dictionaries explicitly:

Iterate through each key-value pair in the original dictionary.
Check if the value is a string and invert.
If the value is a dictionary, iterate through it and add all the numbers to the inverted dictionary.

Here's how you might implement it:
contacts_inv = {}
for key, value in contacts.items():
    if isinstance(value, str):
        if value in contacts_inv:
            contacts_inv[value].append(key)
        else:
            contacts_inv[value] = [key]
    elif isinstance(value, dict):
        for sub_key, sub_value in value.items():
            if sub_value in contacts_inv:
                contacts_inv[sub_value].append(key)
            else:
                contacts_inv[sub_value] = [key]
print(contacts_inv)

